# Testing theoretical properties of Multinomial Elastic Net

Tags: glmnet, elastic-net

Consider the multinomial elastic net regression model.

As explained in http://statweb.stanford.edu/~jhf/ftp/glmnet.pdf (page 12+13), the penalty term imposes a normalization of the parameter estimates across groups. As such, assuming that $\bar{\beta}_{j} \leq \beta_j^M$ as in the paper, the mean and the median of the normalized parameter estimates will satisfy (if I'm not mistaken):

$\frac{1}{K} \sum_{l=1}^K (\beta_{jl}-c_j(\alpha)) \leq 0,$
and the median of the vector $\beta_{jl}-c_j(\alpha)$ in turn has to be greater than or equal to zero. These inequalities will of course flip if we assume that $\bar{\beta}_{j} \geq \beta_j^M$.

Any ideas as to how one could investigate/test these theoretical properties empirically (using glmnet)?